# Make ASP.NET application using Notepad

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have made an ASP.NET application using Notepad++. For this exercise I do not want to use Visual Studio, or any other tool. I want to understand the process.

I have created my website, and it is up and running fine, and all working well.

Now I want to add some C# code behind the pages, both for the master page and for individual pages.

So far, I have a file called **Home.aspx**, and I want to add a C# file to this.

I have created a file called **Home.aspx.cs**. Below is the full content of the file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("LOAD");
    Response.End();
}
```

But when the page loads, this file is not loading. Obviously I am missing something, but I am not sure what. Possibly a reference in my web.config or some other folder, or language reference to tell the page this is C#, or something to tell Page_Load to actually run?

Also, I want to do the same thing for my master page, which is currently called **masterPage.master**.

So would I make a file called **masterPage.master.cs**, or is it a totally different way, or can this even be done?

All references to this problem explain how to do this in Visual Studio, which I do not want to use.

Comment: What does the source of the aspx file look like?

Comment: Have you actually compiled the code? Because an application doesn't work based on its *.cs files. It gets built based on the code, and the resulting .dll/.exe are the application, not the original .cs file.

Comment: I've not tried anything like this before. Have you referenced the cs code behind file in the aspx? What about dll references in the config?

Comment: @Flater - I was wondering about compiling but figured that may possibly be done by IIS

Comment: Take a look at the MSBuild tool. I have had some scripts before where I used MSBuild to build asp.net applications. Then I actually created the project in VS, but continued using Notepad. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @MatthewNorth: I know vNext uses a similar approach, but it needs a framework specifically set up for it. From OP's questions, I infer he's trying to do it "oldschool" and literally just dropped a code file in the directory, not actually compiling.

Comment: You should probably use Visual studio just to see how it does it, then see how you can do it without visual studio.  There are free versions of visual studio.   Or you can beat your head against a wall...

Comment: But does the code need to be built? As far as I know, this type of C# page does not go in the DLL. When I use VS for an asp.net application, if I make changes to the 'Home.aspx.cs' page I do not need to compile the code for these changes to take effect, I just need osave the page?

Comment: @user4420358 Of course all .cs code gets compiled. In fact, when you deploy you shouldn't upload any .cs file, only the .aspx files and the bin folder.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* in fact create an ASP.NET WebForms page without compiling .cs files explicitly.

### Home.aspx

```
<%@ Page Src="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="HomePage" AutoEventWireup="True" %>
```

Notice that the [@ Page directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx) uses the `Src` attribute instead of the usual `CodeBehind` attribute.

(Instead of `Src`, you can alternatively use the `CodeFile` attribute and mark the code-behind class below `partial`.)

### Home.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

public class HomePage : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("LOAD");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

### masterPage.master

```
<%@ Master Src="masterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" AutoEventWireup="True" %>
```

Same thing, except that you use the [@ Master directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228176(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of @ Page.

(Again, instead of `Src`, you can alternatively use the `CodeFile` attribute and mark the code-behind class below `partial`.)

### masterPage.master.cs

```
public class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
}
```

(I named the code-behind class `MasterPage` to match your file name, but to avoid confusion with the built-in ASP.NET `MasterPage` base class, you may want to choose a different name.)

Answer (score 2):

By adding a CodeFile link to the page as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/MasterPage.master" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" Title="Content Page"%>
```

and ensuring an inhereits tag is present, it is not necessary to compile the code.

So this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

The .aspx, .js and .html files in your asp.net app does not need any compilation, but C# is compiled language, so every .cs file needs to be compiled.
You can use some compiler for that purpose or VS command prompt. 
Look at the links as well:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

https://kencenerelli.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/using-notepad-to-write-c-code/

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be compiled in order to run.

It's possible to call msbuild.exe on your solution from the command line.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx